# Drupal: cannot add fields to a View after site move

Tags: drupal, view

I have already received some help on this from other posts in StackOverflow, but there is a specific refinement that does not seem to be addressed.

1. I cloned a Drupal Site.
2. Everything seemed to be working just fine as I worked on CSS per client request.
3. Then along came a client request that involved changes to the fields in a View. No custom field was available in the dialog box - only the default fields. An error showed up at the top of the page:  Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 421 of 16415 bytes in views_db_object->load_row() (line 2251 of /var/www/sitename/html/sites/all/modules/views/includes/view.inc).
4. There had been a change that affected Content Types, but I did not realize that one bad View would cause all of them to fail.
5. It was suggested that I look at another StackOverflow question about this error. One reply said to remove potentially problem Views. When I did that, the error went away.
6. I can now make new Views and have a list of all the available fields, but once I save the View, it goes back to only showing the default fields. There is something else wrong, but I don't know what it is.
   Drupal is always a new puzzle to solve!

Comment: Clone the site again - that would be the easier solution.

Comment: After further investigation, it seems that the problem wasn't the cloning process. The purpose of the clone was to test an upgrade. The problem seems to be in the upgrade!